# How to calculate date difference and display in days and hour format in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

please let me know how to calculate date difference and display in days and hour format in SQL. The table and required result is given in the attached screenshot. Please refer the same.

[image]

Comment: I dont think this is a duplicate question, the other question just gives me in hour and minute format. I need it in days format also.

Comment: Here's a link that may help you. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/82052/3/0

Comment: If you have a moment, could you post your ultimate solution as an answer? I was getting some funny answers form the sqlfiddle, and I have no Oracle server available, so I didn't want to add one myself. @rinson-jimmy

Comment: EXTRACT(DAY FROM (END_TIME - START_TIME) DAY TO SECOND) || 'D ' ||  EXTRACT(HOUR FROM (END_TIME - START_TIME) DAY TO SECOND) || 'H ' || EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM (END_TIME - START_TIME) DAY TO SECOND) || 'M' "Duration" - this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can use this provided your date is in the DB datetime format

```
SELECT CONCAT(
FLOOR(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(T1.START, T1.END)) / 24), ' D ',
MOD(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(T1.START, T1.END)), 24), ' H ',
MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(T1.START, T1.END)), ' M')
FROM TABLE1 T1
```

Comment: ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments  - getting this error while trying your method

Comment: @rinsonjimmy `ORA-00909` is an Oracle error message but you tagged your question with MySql.

Comment: Corrected that. please give me a solution for the above

Comment: @rinsonjimmy - please learn the lesson that tagging your question correctly is very important if you want to get timely and helpful answers.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT 
    (Cast(DATEDIFF(hour, start, end) as varchar) + 
        'H ' +
         Cast(DATEDIFF(minute, start, end)as varchar)) AS Duration;, 
    ID 
from table1;
```

Or

```sql
SELECT 
    (Cast(DATEDIFF(hour, t.start, t.end) as varchar) + 
        'H ' +
        Cast(DATEDIFF(minute, t.start, t.end)as varchar)) AS Duration;, 
    ID 
from table1 t;
```